# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in Swift 3

Tags: swift3

I have a timetable app, and after converting everything to Swift 3, one particular line threw an EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error, stating "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Here is the code, the final line returns the error:

```
 class CyclicDay {
            enum CyclicDayError: Error {
                case invalidStartDate }
            lazy var baseline: Date! = {
                var components = DateComponents()
                components.day = 27
                components.month = 3
                components.year = 2017
                return Calendar.current.date(from: components)!
            }()
            func dayOfCycle(_ testDate: Date) throws -> Int {
                if let start = baseline {
                    let interval = testDate.timeIntervalSince(start as Date)
                    let days = interval / (60 * 60 * 24)
                    return Int(days.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 14)) + 1 }
             throw CyclicDayError.invalidStartDate }}



    override func viewDidLoad() {

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let cd = CyclicDay()
        let day = try! cd.dayOfCycle(Date())
        let date = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let components = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: date)
        let hour = components.hour
        let minutes = components.minute
        _ = "\(String(describing: hour)):\(String(describing: minutes))"

        let lengthTestHour = "\(String(describing: hour))"
        let lengthTestMinute = "\(String(describing: minutes))"

        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "a"
        formatter.amSymbol = "AM"
        formatter.pmSymbol = "PM"

        let dateString = formatter.string(from: Date())

        var finalHour = String()
        if lengthTestHour.characters.count == 1 {
            finalHour = String("0\(String(describing: hour))")
        } else {
             finalHour = "\(String(describing: hour))"
        }
        if lengthTestMinute.characters.count == 1 {
            _ = "0\(String(describing: minutes))"
        } else {_ = minutes }
        let convert = finalHour
        let mTime = Int(convert)


        // mTime * 100 + minutes
        let compTime = mTime! * 100 + minutes!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift 3 all date components are optional, you need to unwrap the optionals

```
let hour = components.hour!
let minutes = components.minute!
```

otherwise you get in trouble with the string interpolations.

Btw: You don't need `String(describing` just write for example

```
_ = "\(hour):\(minutes)"
```

I'm wondering anyway why you do all the formatting stuff *manually* instead of using the date formatter you created.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in these two lines:

```
let lengthTestHour = "\(String(describing: hour))"
let lengthTestMinute = "\(String(describing: minutes))"
```

You thought `lengthTestHour` will store a value like `"7"` and `lengthTestMinute` will have a value like `"33"`. But no, `lengthTestHours` actually holds `"Optional(7)"` and `lengthTestMinutes` actually holds `"Optional(33)"`.

You then assign `lengthTestHour` to `convert` and try to convert that `Optional(7)` thing into an Int, which obviously can't be done. Now `mTime` is `nil` and you try to force unwrap in the last line. BOOM!

This is because `String(describing:)` returns an optional. The two lines can be shortened and fixed by doing:

```
let lengthTestHour = "\(hour!)"
let lengthTestMinute = "\(minute!)"
```